# How can I export default interface if export default is object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

**types.d.ts**

```
export interface Messenger {
  user: string,
  message: string
}

export default {
    Messenger,
};
```

when I want to import `Messenger` interface to others file by import default it said not found.

**index.ts**

```
import types from "./types";

export { types };

export default {
    types,
};
```

But I found an error that is `Error: Cannot find module './types'` in `index.ts`

I expect I can export default all things in file `type.d.ts` to import after that export again.

Comment: you don't need your `export default` - you are slightly mixing types and runtime values

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a `types.d.ts` file, just `*.ts` fill will suffice.

Here I use **Messenger.interface.ts**, not that the part **.interface.** is not necessary, but shows the intent of the file.

Here is an example:

**Messenger.interface.ts**

```
export default interface Messenger {
    user: string;
    message: string;
}
```

**index.ts**

```
import Message from "./Message.interface";

export default Message;
```

Also note that when defining interfaces in TypeScript they are separated by semicolumns (**;**) rather than commas (**,**).